# Show two tooltips on d3.curveLinearClosed?

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js

I need your help!
I have to show a tooltip on the curve using d3, I already have that functionality and it does work, but now I have to show two separated tooltips on one curve.

Let me explain, I used to use [this](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#curveLinear) curve appearance, it is a simple d3 curve, and the tooltip works perfectly. And now need to use this curve appearance -
https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#curveLinearClosed

[image]

And I'd like to know how to show one tooltip on the bottom of the curve and a second on the top.
So far my implementation of the tooltip works only on the top, I think that happens because d3 draws the bottom line on its own.
So did anybody have a similar problem?

This is a picture how it should look like:
[image]

I do not need the code, I'd like to hear any thoughts or ideas about that.

Comment: could you maybe add an image or drawing of exactly what your end result may look like?

Comment: Alfonso Irarrázaval - I added the screenshot what I exactly need

Comment: Ok, so are you wondering how to get the coordinate where to add the second tooltip? or how to add the second tooltip altogether?